# MongoDB replica set initial Sync

Tags: mongodb

Doing initial sync to the secondary is a very time consuming process, I haven't found anywhere in MongoDB docs that the primary can accept write operations during the initial Sync, or if not recommended. Is it safe to keep the primary operational (for write) during this process?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a primary to accept a write there have to be at least a quorum of voting replica set members available to vote and vote for the same primary. For instance for a 3 member replica set you need at least 2.

A secondary that is in initial sync should be in the Recovering state and according to the documentation can vote http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-states/:

> 3     RECOVERING  Can vote. Members either perform startup self-checks,
>   or transition from completing a rollback or resync.

Now should you? I think the question depends on how many members were in the set before. If you've been running with 2 data nodes and 1 arbiter, running with 1 data node only for awhile is something only you can answer - yes it's riskier but what's your alternative, being down completely?

If you have 3 data nodes and 1 is down for an initial sync I don't see much issue unless you have very high data redundancy needs.

If you are starting from only having 1 node and you are transitioning into a replica set well you are no worse off then you were before.

Above all else always make certain you have at least 3 members of your replica set, preferably with at least 2 data nodes and generally speaking an odd number of voters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer John, very helpful. Sorry I forgot to include my config, it is 1 primary, 1 secondary, and 1 arbiter, in this case ,I agree, and I as I thought, It can but with a risk. For now, initial Sync is almost done, but good to know for later if I need to do it again, which is likely.